# Python: split list of values into two list of values. Sums of list should be as equal as possible

Tags: python, algorithm, list

So, I am a python newbee... thanks for advice.

I am a vinyl mastering engineer and I often need to rearrange song orders in order to keep running times on each side of the vinyl as low as possible (for quality reasons). Normally, I do it by hand - trial and error.

Now, that I am learning python for some weeks, I thought it would be the right problem to solve this in a little script.

So I have a list of pairs (Songnumber, Length).
How do I calculate two song-lists, that are both closest to the half total playing time of the album?

Thanks!

Edit01:
So here is what I managed to code thanks to Heath. It seems to work :)

```
from itertools import combinations

song_lengths = [3.20, 2.40, 6.34, 1.20, 3.30, 4.12]

total_time = sum(song_lengths)
print("Totaltime: " + str(total_time))

half_time = total_time / 2
print("Halftime: " + str(half_time))

diff_time = half_time

for n in range(len(song_lengths)):

    for first_half in combinations(song_lengths, n):
        if abs(half_time - sum(first_half)) < diff_time:
            diff_time = half_time - sum(first_half)
            perfect_half = first_half

print("The perfect combination is " + str(perfect_half) + " with a total   playing time of " + str(sum(perfect_half)))
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried and at least hand us a list with the times of tracks. Then you might get better help.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/partition-a-set-into-two-subsets-such-that-the-difference-of-subset-sums-is-minimum/ This is exact problem that you are trying to solve. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like many programming challenges, this is a matter of finding equivalent problems which are easier or better understood, and solving them.

So first, notice that it doesn't matter what the second side length is - if the first is close to half the total length than the second will be too (by the same amount). Now we just have to find a set of songs which is close to the half the total length.

That set could have one or more songs (up to one less than the total number), but their order doesn't affect the playing time. The process of choosing a set of one or more elements from a larger set, where the order doesn't matter, is called a *combination*.

Fortunately, Python makes it very simple to iterate through combinations. Start with something like this:

```
from itertools import combinations

song_lengths = []#fill in your song lengths here

for first_half in combinations(song_lengths, 1):
    #check total length of first_half - if it's the best we've seen, then keep a record
```

Now all you need to do is wrap the `for` loop in another `for` which increases the number of tracks in the first_half from `1` (as it is in my example) to one less total number of tracks, going up by one each time.

This ought to get you started. If you get stuck, feel free to come back and ask a more specific question.

Side note: this solution doesn't "scale" in the sense that it will become intolerably slow as the number of songs increases. I suspect you'll never need to do this for more than about 20 songs, but if you do then this solution will no longer be much use!

Comment: Thanks very much, Heath!
(and very didactical, too :))
I'll get startet soon...

Comment: woohoo, it works!
How can I add code here? I would like to show you.

Comment: What would be a good data structure if I wanted to have the following for each track:
track_number (could be the index)
track_name (should be a string)
track_time (should be a float)

and how would you iterate over it?

Comment: It came to my mind, that my song lengths are in minutes and seconds. So probably adding them as floats is not the right way to do it, no?

Comment: Try a `list` of `tuples`. And yeah, either convert min:sec to just seconds (integer) or just minutes (float). Eg. seconds = min*60 + sec or minutes = min + sec/60.